# Why doesn't this.find() work inside my plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery accordion plugin and can't figure out why doesn't the 'this' keyword work as it should. Here's the code of the plugin:

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.accrdn = function(userSettings) {
    var defaults = { 
        toggle: true
    };
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, userSettings);
    var handle = this.find('.handle');//doesn't work!

    if (options.toggle) {
        handle.click(function(){
            $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle();
        });
    } else {
        handle.click(function(){
            $(this).next('.panel').slideUp();
        });
    };
};
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Can you include how you're using the plugin? Sample markup and calling code? Possibly a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: please show the markup generated by the plugin - calling `this.find()` is perfectly legal, although a well-behaved plugin would use `this.each()` to apply it to every supplied element, or `this.first().find()` to ensure it only applies to the first matching element.

Comment: "does'nt work" how exactly? Is the selector empty, as in no element found, or does it throw an error in the console. The syntax seems perfectly valid !

Comment: Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3KZqH/

Comment: adeneo, no error is thrown in the console. it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Now that the OP has provided an example fiddle of the code usage, the problem is the selector for the accordion div, it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordion').accrdn({toggle:true, slideSpeed:500});
});
```

NOTE: The selector was missing the `.` to identify it is a `class` selector

[Here is the fix](http://jsfiddle.net/3KZqH/1/)

Comment: +1.  FWIW, plenty other folks put effort into this one too, they just couldn't answer it _correctly_ at first because the OP hadn't supplied enough information.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, but I am the one that stuck around and put in the extra effort. I cannot be held responsible for the original 5 people who agreed with my answer and also thought it was correct, I think it would be fair to also say that those 5 people would have likely retained the upvote having seen my updated answer (assuming they hadn't already seen it anyway)